# Create a new matching-tag-pair textobject?

Tags: vimscript, custom-text-object, markup

Vim provides a builtin textobject `t` that captures a matched pair of HTML tags — so e.g. if you start with `this <i>that█ <b>those</b></i>`, then typing `dat` in normal mode leaves you with `this█`. Very cool.

How might I create similar textobjects for other markup languages with this sort of begin/end syntax? For instance, if I wanted one that captures the a matched pair of Liquid tags, or a matched LaTeX `\begin{foo}` and `\end{foo}` tag pair, where might I start?

I'm willing to do some digging and to write my own code, but seeing an example where someone has accomplished something similar would be very helpful.

Comment: Heh, apparently all I do on this site is ask questions about custom textobjects

Comment: General thoughts for possible answers: there are plugins that support making custom text objects; there are various web tutorials; probably things I’m missing. (A link does not an answer make—we expect the most relevant information to be contained directly in the answer itself. Include the link as a source and companion, and please attribute material.)

Comment: So I've done a bit of digging on the plugin front. https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user seems to be the standard recommendation. It does allow for textobjects that are defined by "find beginning" and "find end" functions. But it doesn't allow for the one to pass information to the other — to the "find beginning" function can't say to the other one "The opening tag I found was a `foo` tag, please look for a `/foo` in particular." I think that prevents it from handling this. If there's a plugin with that feature, I haven't seen it recommended, though I'll certainly keep googling.

Comment: Glad youre finding things! My comment was mostly aimed at potential answer writers

Comment: Oh! Sorry! I thought you might be checking if I'd done my homework. :) I appreciate the thoughts in any case.

Comment: For LaTeX check out a more specific plug-in, such as https://github.com/lervag/vimtex (I know that doesn't cover the general case, but a language-specific plug-in is usually able to do a better job of matching custom tags or markers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know a reference to a plugin is not an ideal answer, but this is a tricky thing to accomplish generally and I maintain a plugin which seems to do exactly what you ask for so I'll mention it.

The plugin [match-up](https://github.com/andymass/vim-matchup/) supports text objects `a%` and `i%` corresponding to pairs which were originally defined by matchit's `%` (*matchit* is a built-in plugin in vim which supports only visual-mode `a%` and  is a bit inconsistent).

You can customize it with `b:match_words` like so:

```
au FileType file let b:match_words = '\begin{\(\w\+\)}:\end{\1},(:)'
```

It supports LaTeX out of the box (more extensively than VimTeX), and you probably won't need to define your own pairs for many languages.

Answer (score 0):

one of the cool plugins to trait tag is vim surround
let's try out visual mode the `that█`  then:`S<i>.`

```
this <i> that█   <i>
```

to remove this tag use  `d` `s` `t`

#### OR do manually

- if you want to delete a tag
  `vatatd`

  - `vat` select select by tag
  - `at` extend select to another outside tag
  - ... you can extend tag also if you want
  - `d` delete selected text
- if you want to remove the tag only
  `yitvatatp`

  - `yit` yank text
  - `vat` select select by tag
  - `at` extend select to another outside tag
  - ... you can extend tag also if you want
  - `p` past yanked text

Comment: Looks like you missed the part of the question where OP want’s text objects for things similar to XML tags (such as LaTeX environment delimiters).